# Which library should I use for Location when using google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-location-services

I have the following library for the google maps and it works fine

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
```

But when I try to add this one for location,

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.1.0'
```

the following error occurs

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.1.0
```

Which library for the location should I use?
THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

You will get latest gradle dependencies here

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because 16.1.0 does not exist for this library. Google Play Services libraries do not always have the same version. So maps might be on 16.1.0 but location might not even have this version.

To get the latest versions, check the official release page: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

And as you are just starting, make sure to use the latest ones:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0
```

Yes, it is a coincident that those versions are currently the same. As you can see in the list there are already libraries on 19.0.0, like appindexing

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0
```

*Edit*

A small practical tip: If you replace the version by + and sync the project, gradle will get the newest one and afterwards you can use the IDE warning to replace the + again with the newest version number. That eases a bit the checking on different pages if there is a new version or not etc

Comment: @Sam. yes and no. As he said maps lib works, so the repo is available already

Comment: used com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0 and it worked. Thank you!